# Push objects to array and get the array content

Tags: jquery

I get results from Ajax call and want to push it to an array as objects;

This is my try:

```
var myList = [""];

$.ajax({
    url: 'list.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            myList.push({
                id: data[i].id,
                text: data[i].text
            });
        }
        console.log(myList);

    }
});
```

**The output I get is:**

```
["",Object, Object, Object, ...]
```

I'm wondering how can I get the output like this:

```
["", {id:"id", text:"text"}, {id:"id", text:"text"}, ...]
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** method to convert the object to JSON string.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myList));
```

---

**UPDATE :** Your question output is not a valid json, to convert into that format use `String#replace` method.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myList).replace(/({\s?|,\s?)"(\w+)":/g,'$1$2:'));
```

Comment: Thanks! ... But there's a small thing is not okay with that, it's returning **BOTH** the key pair between double quotes: `{"id":"id"}` , how can I make it surround the data only with quotes, to be `{id:"id"}` ?

Comment: @Homer : that's valid json... otherwise try `console.log(JSON.stringify(myList).replace(/{"(\w+)":/g,'{$1:'));`

Comment: Thanks again Pranav!

Comment: Would you please help in refining the replace a little, to make it replace the other key? since it's replacing the first one only! :) `{id: "id", "text": "text"}`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Easy!

```
JSON.stringify(myList);
```

Should take care of it for you.